# Transformer experiment

Tags: experimental-physics

Are there any experiments conducted where we test a transformer by inputting more iron cores in to the original solenoid linking the output and the input voltage? I asked several questions on this but I am not seeming to get an answer and am getting curious. I would appreciate some clarification or sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is done during the design process for a transformer. The designer varies the amount of iron in the core until (s)he is satisfied that there is just enough iron present to prevent core saturation at the intended power level for the transformer.

Comment: thank you for the kind and useful reply. So that implies that more iron cores means more output voltage if we initially start from a very weak magnetic core? How would the out voltage vary as we keep adding more cores, experimentally I expect it will increase linearly but will that be the case?

Comment: Are there any sources or links which relate to this experiment in the initial stages I can have a look at?

Comment: More iron cores mean more *current*, not more voltage. If you visit the webpage of a company that manufactures custom transformers you will probably find a tutorial on the subject of transformer design.

Comment: Does this imply that by the equation:
$$\frac{I_s}{I_p}=\frac{V_p}{V_s}$$ 

Since, $I_p$ increases and $I_s$ will get smaller over time as there will be some losses as it is moving through the iron core, then it means given $V_p$ remains constant, $V_p$ will therefore increase?

Comment: Core losses show up as efficiency losses in the transformer overall: The power (V x I) in the secondary will always be a bit less than (V x I) in the primary.