# Are Idealized Transformers Realizable?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, capacitance, material-science, inductance

Since parasitic capacitance in an inductor is always [in parallel with its inductance](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/122038), would this effectively become analogous to [magnetic remanence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remanence) [exhibited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_magnetic_material) within [rebars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebar) (made from carbon steel) suggesting that [idealized](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/e-transformerdc.html) transformers may, in fact, be realizable by using hard magnetic materials to fabricate their cores (suitable for permanent magnets) instead of the commonly used soft magnetic materials and [increasing their iron cores to increase their current](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/481092/transformer-experiment)?

I don't know how an increased remanence, or an increased parallel (parasitic) capacitance, or both, could diminish a transformer's dependency upon being designed for specific frequencies and, thus, for this reason do I seek an answer.

Comment: To be sure, an ideal transformer is flat from "DC-to-light", i.e., there is no frequency dependence. I don't think it imaginable that this could be realizable (thus the adjective "ideal"). But I'm curious to hear more about what you have in mind if not this.

Comment: We can't even realize idealized inductors. Ideal transformers also would not saturate so you can pretty much forget using a core. Judging from your wording though what you're asking about isn't about an ideal transformer as much as as a transformer with X parasitic.